# Does it sorts NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting

I have singleton named `storeScores` in that class I have a scores `NSMutableArray`. I want to find the high score (which is the lowest float in array) and print it with my viewController. I'm calling this method to make the array sorted and take the lowest number in it.

```
-(NSString*)getHighscore{
    NSMutableArray *scores2 = _scores;
    NSString *highest;
    float highScore;
    NSSortDescriptor *highestToLowest = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];
    [scores2 sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:highestToLowest]];
    highScore = [[scores2 firstObject]floatValue];
    highest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",highScore];
    return highest;
}
```

When I do this I see '0.00' on the label. When I do `highScore = [[scores2 objectAtIndex:0]floatValue];` instead of `highScore = [[scores2 firstObject]floatValue];`, the app crashes. What is the problem?

Comment: how does your array look with the scores? could you post that as well, please?

Comment: The array is probably empty so calling `objectAtIndex: 0` will throw an index out of bounds error. Try logging the sorted array just to make sure.

Comment: If `objectAtIndex:0` crashes, it means your array is empty. `-firstObject` won't crash but just returns `nil` in that case, and then sending `-floatValue` to `nil` results in 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better performance to sort your array, I suggest you to do this in this way:

```
- (NSNumber*)getHighscore{

    if(_scores.count >= 1) {
        float minValue = MAXFLOAT; // minValue = highest score
        for (NSNumber *number in _scores) {
            float x = number.floatValue;
            if (x < minValue) minValue = x;
        }
        return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:minValue];
    }
    else
        return nil;
}
```

Use this method like this:

```
NSLog(@"Lowest value (highest score): %@", [[self getHighscore] stringValue]);
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/objectAtIndex:). `firstObject`:

> **Return Value** 
>  The first object in the array. If the array is empty,
>   returns nil.

`objectAtIndex:`:

> **Return Value** 
>  The object located at index.
>
> **Discussion** 
>  If index is beyond the end of the array (that is, if index
>   is greater than or equal to the value returned by count), an
>   NSRangeException is raised.

Hence the only thing that could account for the different behaviour you're seeing is: the array does not have an object at index 0. It is empty.

Add an `NSLog` of `_scores` or `scores2` to confirm.

Comment: Thank you all, array was empty because I've forgotten to load the array from NSUserDefaults.